# Can I use a nested list structure as a feature for a logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, feature-selection, nested-data

Suppose I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
alert_id  hour  feature_1  feature_2
1234      0     00         0.06
1234      1     12         1.15
1234      2     15         0.98
1234      3     12         0.00
1234      4     00         0.00
1234      5     00         0.00
5678      0     00         0.00
5678      1     00         0.00
5678      2     00         0.00
5678      3     18         1.32
5678      4     34         -1.05
5678      5     12         0.52
9123      0     00         0.00
```

This dataset represents the state (aka what the feature values were at each hour) of my system for the past i-th hour whenever an alert was created. I believe that it is important for my logistic regression model to see that state of my system in order for it to correctly classify each alert into either events A, B, or C.

I was thinking I can transpose each alert record into a nest list feature that will look like this:

```
[[hour 0, feature1, feature2], [[hour 1, feature1, feature2], ... [[hour H, feature1, feature2]]
```

OR do I use 10 features (meaning that the feature at every hour become its own unique feature?) That looks like this:

```
feature_1_at_0_hour, feature_2_at_0_hour, feature_1_at_1_hour, feature_2_at_1_hour... etc.
```

I feel that the former representation makes more sense in the event that number of hours is not exactly 5

Comment: There are two ways. One is by looping and another is by using lapply(). How will the alerts be categorized into events (A, B, C)?

Comment: @Mohanasundaram so we actually that specialists that manually label each alert (they look at the overall state of the system during the past couple of hours before they make their evaluation), so I already have each datapoint labeled for my training set. My concern is whether what I am trying to do is actually "correct" or even possible

Comment: you can subset the data categorize the alerts in a loop. I understand that you are labeling the events based on the states of the system. I'll update you the code, if that will help you.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram So it is valid to use a nested list structure as a feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dataset into list of subsets and carryout the classification.

```
datalist <- split(data, data$alert_id)
```